# Format a datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `tblTest` which has a field called `e_date` which has a type of `DateTime`.

I would like to know is there a method which would allow me to format in SQL so that this field only shows the date in `'d mmm yyyy'` when the stored procedure is ran.

On SQL server 2008 R2

I have found a method to do this which show the date as i would please,  but when i try and changing the format so that it only shows the date, the data associated with it does not show.

CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), [Date_ex], 6) AS ExamDates,

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The RDBMS I am using is SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Look for a date_format function. In MySQL it would be something like:

```
//Syntax
DATE_FORMAT({date},{format})

//Example
DATE_FORMAT("2012-04-27",'%d/%m/%Y')
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Pinal Dave's function in this article. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/14/sql-server-get-date-time-in-any-format-udf-user-defined-functions/

For intance, after you create the function, you can call it by the following

```
select [dbo].[ufsFormat] (getdate(),'mm/dd/yy')
```

This is MS SQL though. You did not mention what RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MSSQL based on you history; for SQL Server 2012 simply use `FORMAT()`

Otherwise its a bit fiddly to drop a leading zero;

```
select
  substring(case when day(e_date) < 10 then '' else '?' end + convert(char(11), e_date, 106), 2, 32)
```